# Can multiple Java processes read the same file at the same time?

Tags: java, linux, file, concurrency, io

Is it possible to read the same file from two or more different processes at the same time?

I'd like to do something like this in a Java application:

```
final File f = new File("read-only-file");
final FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
int b;
while((b = in.read()) != null) {
    //process b
    Thread.sleep(10); //several read processes would really happen at the same time
}
```

No application would ever write to the file but several threads/applications need to execute the code above at the same time. Is the code above fine or do I need to use any special mechanisms in that case?

Also the solution should be platform-independent and must work on Linux like systems.

Comment: You can try this relatively easily, but the answer is yes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Then write an answer please so that I can accept it as one.

Comment: It will likely make your HDD go crazy - unless you have an SSD or some sort of RAID.

Comment: @BoristheSpider what do you make of the fs cache?

Comment: @fge depends on the file size I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can multiple Java processes read the same file at the same time?

Sure they can; and ultimately, it is the role of the OS anyway to ensure that each process/thread reads at its own pace, so you need not worry about it.

Of course, you may want to share as many resources as possible between the different threads, but certainly not the I/O streams; and while we are at it, use the new file API if you use Java 7 or upper (this is 2014; it's been 3 years since Java 7 is there); `File` is a very inferior API compared to java.nio.file (and, in fact, compared to the file manipulation APIs of most programming languages in general).

Comment: If I execute the code in the question several times at the same time (in different threads), will the `File` and `FileInputStream` objects be identical so that the `FileInputStream`s have the same current reading position? Or will `new File(path)` always return distinct objects with distinct streams when called several times?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock `File` is essentially a wrapper around a `String` representing the path to the file in question. `new File` doesn't _open_ anything. `new FileInputStream` will return a new stream each time.